# Grouping SSRS column values that are similar

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

This is a difficult question to articulate, but I'll give it my best:

Basically my database has erroneous values and I want to write my SSRS to account for them rather than going in and cleaning up the DB.

For simplicity's sake my records consist of 2 values: **ownerid** and **case_type**. Currently we have case_types that are lexicographically similar but conceptually identical. I want to create a report for records to account for these data inconsistencies. So...

I would ideally like to turn a simple call center report like this:

```
Owner | Email | Inbound Phone | Inbound Phone Call
bob   |  3    |     5         |     7
jon   |  1    |     2         |     3
```

Where for each owner responded to x number of emails, y number of 'inbound phone' and z number of 'inbound phone calls'. (I didn't create this data and am the one dealing with it now).

into:

```
Owner | Email | Inbound Phone Call
bob   |  3    |     12
jon   |  1    |     5
```

Essentially combining the count of 'inbound phone' and 'inbound phone call' records into a single column.

PS This data is coming from CRM 2011 and I need to use Fetch as the query. I have all the records I need, I just need to figure out how to parse the bad ones.

Comment: So your data has two columns, OwnerID and case_type. What are your values? The number of occurences or a sum of a third column?

Comment: For my example there are 3 values for the case_type and 2 owners. Essentially there are 5 records where the owner is bob AND the case_type is Inbound Phone. Likewise there are 7 records where the owner is bob and the case_type is Inbound Phone Call. I want to instruct the report to combine these #s and give me 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSRS creates a new column whenever it thinks it is encountering a new group. The report you started with used a field for this. So SSRS thought every distinct value in the [Case_type] field was a new group, and needed a new column.

So change the group properties (Right click on gray area above the column and select Column Group -> Group Properties... Edit the Group Expression to the formula below)

The formula below should replace a the simple field. Before creating a new group, SSRS will run every [case_type] through this formula, and if it is "Inbound Phone" it will be replaced with "Inbound Phone Call."  SSRS will now see that this matches an existing group and will group these values in the same column.

```
=Switch(
  Fields!Case_Type.Value = "Inbound Phone", "Inbound Phone Call",
  1 = 1, Fields!Case_Type.Value)
```

Other replacements can be inserted into this to handle additional cases. If you need them combined by similarity, then things can get more complicated.

Comment: Hmm, I should have made that more clear, my fields aren't named "Inbound Phone". My field is named case_type and the value(s) in them are "Email", "Inbound Phone" and "Inbound Phone Call". So when I set up my matrix it only has 1 row and 1 column. The row is [ownerid] and the column is [case_type]. I was able to figure out how to filter the column values so that "Inbound Phone" does not appear. But when I wanted to see the corrected data I wasn't able to get very far: =IIf(Fields!case_type.Value = "Inbound Phone Call",0,Count(Fields!case_type.Value))  What do I put in place of 0?

Comment: As far as I know the only 2 values that I want to combine are Inbound Phone and Inbound Phone Call. Someone screwed up the records and now I need to write a report that can handle them.

Comment: I just tried sticking that Switch expression into the column header and all it did was replace the text "Inbound Phone" with "Inbound Phone Call". I still had 3 columns, except now I had 2 named "Inbound Phone Call". I need to be able to merge the data within those 2 and only show 1 result column.

Comment: I hate to look a gift horse in the mouth, but could you help me understand **why** this works?

Comment: Happy to add more **why**. Teach a man to fish and all.. I've edited the answer. Let me know if you'd like more on some point. (You might consider deleting some of these comments to leave the question in a clean state for future visitors.)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL query to achieve result looks like

```
SELECT t1.[owner_id]
  ,(    select  sum([case_value]) 
        from    [dbo].[Table_1] t2 
        where   t2.case_type in ('email') 
                and t2.owner_id = t1.owner_id) as 'Email'

  ,(    select  sum([case_value]) 
        from    [dbo].[Table_1] t3 
        where   t3.case_type in ('inbound phone', 'inbound phone call') 
                and t3.owner_id = t1.owner_id) as 'Phone'
  FROM [dbo].[Table_1] t1
  GROUP BY t1.owner_id
```

I don't think that it's possible to write so complex query using Fetch XML. Only you are able to write Fetch XML for each from cells in your result table and it will looks like

```
<fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'> 
<entity name='your_entity_name'>
<attribute name='value_column' alias='value_column_sum' aggregate='sum' />
<filter type='and'>
    <condition attribute='case_type' operator='eq' value='desired_value_1' />
    <condition attribute='case_type' operator='eq' value='desired_value_2' />
</filter>
</entity> 
</fetch>
```

Comment: Are you saying I can change a cell and give it its own fetch? How do I do that? I thought that only the DataSet could use a fetch.